# How to copy data from Powerpoint charts into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a couple of Powerpoint decks the first 3 slides of whom contains charts. Presently, I need to go in each of them and copy data from those charts and paste them in an excel workbook. Is there a way to do this using VBA?

The Powerpoint charts are not pulling data from Excel. I saw another thread which tweaks the data for a Powerpoint table but nothing on charts. Also, I need to copy and paste that data into excel.

Comment: Are the charts pictures or do they have data behind them?   What type of charts are they, embedded or PPT created charts?

Comment: They are PPT created charts. So the data is within the Powerpoint charts' Excel.

Comment: What version of Powerpoint is it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to access the data in 2016, is to access the series collection(s).

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes
if .name = "Chart1" then
"Sheet1!$B$1" = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
```

This is for slide # 2, Chart 1 and series 1.
You can cycle through all the shapes on a slide by using :

```
For Each oSH In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes
```

The easiest way is to name all the shapes you need data from so that you can focus directly on those objects.